# Security onion TLS re-encryption

Tags: security, ssl, monitoring, packet-sniffers, ca

Upon installation of security onion in following production guide from the docs
At some point after I've configured sniffing port one of the windows server boxes on my network has showed a prompt warning of a untrusted CA signed by "securityonion" which is not hostname of my security onion instance.

I have had looked over documentation and there's nothing that would suggest that packets would be re-encrypted with SO CA.
I was also unable identify which service/software would be responsible for this, looking for some hints to troubleshoot this as I really want to know where does this come from.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you provide the error message from the prompt (use triple backticks for paragraph formatting)? This will help both future readers and people who want to answer your question. You may also want to take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask a clearer question.

Comment: [Windows prompt](https://imgur.com/OumFfYk) This is the prompt I am getting

Comment: There’s an edit button on your question. Copy (and obfuscate) text, no images please!